# usb cable identification/use

Tags: usb

I would like to know what this cable is for?  One end is usb and the other end small pin that has a B on it.  the printing on the cable reads:  HI-SPEED USB Revision 2.0 SHIELDED 28/AWG/1PR+26AWG/2C  (UL) E305668 TYPE CM 75o C MSL

Comment: What has windows 7 to do with this (title: windows 7 usb cable usage)

Comment: What does windows 7 have to do with a USB cable?  The cable doesn't care what operating system it is plugged into.

Comment: Any chance you can link to an image?

Answer (score 1):

The 'U' in USB stands for 'Universal'. This means that whatever it fits in, it works with.

The 'B' end is a small form-factor USB connector commonly used by cameras, phones - small portable devices in which a type 'A' USB port (the type you'll find on your computer) would be too big.

Essentially, it's not specifically 'for' anything. A USB cable will work with any device whose port it fits in.

Answer (score 0):

It's a MiniUSB cable.  Connects USB from a computer to items with a small USB (some scanners, some printers, cameras, older cell phones like BB's).

The OS is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some of the cables here at the [Startech Site](http://ca.startech.com/Cables/USB-2.0) and see if something is close.

When you say 'pin" I think of thespecialized USB cables shipped with some digital cameras a few years ago.  Each maker seened to make a unique cable.  They all seem to have come around to standardized USB form factors now.